# Champion challenger experiment, scalability, and rule test of Drools

Tags: drools, rule-engine

While we are trying to make a decision whether to use Drools as our rule engine, there are some features we concern.

1. Could **champion challenger experiment** be carried out (easily if possible) in Drools?
2. What about the **scalability** of Drools? Do we need to change to another rule engine when the facts increase from thousands to millions or even more?
3. Can **rules be tested** before deployment? Can business analyst test rules when they are authoring them, for example in drools workbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If a **champion challenger experiment** can be carried out with the features available in Drools and Java: then it can be carried out. (Since you don't provide a specification of that experiment that's all that can be said.)
- A Drools application can handle millions of facts but (as always) it depends on the resources (time, memory, CPU cyles per second, bandwidth,...) you are prepared to provide.
- Rules can be tested before deployment, like any other SW - it requires skill and effort.
- I am notorious for saying that business analysts aren't SW engineers in the first place, and they aren't SW testers either. If rule system marketing experts try to make you believe otherwise: ask them why car or airplane marketing analysts aren't test drivers or test pilots.

Comment: Thanks, Laune! In a **champion challenger experiment**, we hope Drools can split input facts randomly, for example into two parts, and feed each part to different strategies. And report to us which strategy performs better. Can this be done in Drools? If yes, how? Any tutorials?

Comment: As to the **rule testing**, does it mean that it should be carried out by SW developer or tester? Is there any good tools that can make it easier? Also detailed tutorial is of great help to us. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, definitely. In certain situations you could even prove that a set of rules has certain properties, e.g., fires exactly once for a certain set of facts. Logging (via listeners) can demonstrate a certain level of coverage. Note that testing must show that a rule fires when expected **and also that it does not so when not expected.**

Comment: Hi, Laune, can you give some demo on how to do **champion challenger experiment** in Drools, or some resources? It seems to be quite rare on the internet.